# Why do proper types Any and Nothing fit type constructor shape F[_] when they are different kinds?

Tags: scala, type-parameter, type-constructor

Consider the following method which takes type parameter of `* -> *` kind

```
def g[F[_]] = ???
```

Why is the following not a syntax error

```
g[Any]       // ok
g[Nothing]   // ok
```

since

```
scala> :kind -v Any
Any's kind is A
*
This is a proper type.

scala> :kind -v Nothing
Nothing's kind is A
*
This is a proper type.
```

so `Any` and `Nothing` should be of wrong shape?

Comment: I guess those two are exceptions made by the compiler, since both **Any** and **Nothing** are special and are used when the compiler can not infer anything else.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quotes from Scala spec:

> For every type constructor  (with any number of type parameters), `scala.Nothing <:  <: scala.Any`.

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#conformance

> Say the type parameters have lower bounds `1,…,` and upper bounds `1,…,`. The parameterized type is well-formed if each actual type parameter conforms to its bounds, i.e. `<:<:` where  is the substitution `[1:=1,…,:=]`.

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#parameterized-types

> A polymorphic method type is denoted internally as `[tps]` where `[tps]` is a type parameter section `[1 >: 1 <: 1,…, >:  <: ]` for some `≥0` and  is a (value or method) type. This type represents named methods that take type arguments `1,…,` which conform to the lower bounds `1,…,` and the upper bounds `1,…,` and that yield results of type .

https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/03-types.html#polymorphic-method-types

So since `Any` and  `Nothing` conform to upper and lower bounds of `F[_]` (namely, `Any` and  `Nothing` correspondingly), `g[Any]` and `g[Nothing]` are legal.